# Can't use specific images in Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I've got a problem with a pipeline in which I want to build ARM images. 
So, I was willing to use an arm32v7 image to run as build agent:

> ```
> pipeline {
>     agent {
>         docker {
>             image 'arm32v7/docker:dind'
>         }
>     }
>     stages {
>         stage('Build atom images') {
>             steps {
>                 // Building my images.
>         }
>         stage('Push to registry') {
>             agent any
>             steps{
>                 script {
>                     withDockerRegistry(credentialsId: 'cred', url: 'https://registry.custom') {
>                         // Pushing images to registry.
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But, when pipeline runs, here's what I got:

```
+ docker inspect -f . arm32v7/docker:dind 
. 
Failed to run top '81cc646256b727780420048da5ff10e5a3256510fc8a787137651941ee54d8a0'. Error: Error response from daemon: Container 81cc646256b727780420048da5ff10e5a3256510fc8a787137651941ee54d8a0 is not running
```

This happens with every kind of image I choose. Can you help me on this? Am i missing something?

Comment: What is the log before the `inspect`?

Comment: > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1bd2db3baaccbbda2d17885c8f0ab9dcf5bcfe04
Commit message: "Creating custom builder on debian"
+ docker inspect -f . arm32v7/docker:dind
.
Failed to run top '3328d29c2ad7d1f0d3f5514b92a401a55b19eea05c6ed67ae4af5f954c3604b1'. Error: Error response from daemon: Container 3328d29c2ad7d1f0d3f5514b92a401a55b19eea05c6ed67ae4af5f954c3604b1 is not running

Comment: Could you try to run the container on the machine directly with SSH? `docker run -it --rm `arm32v7/docker:dind bash`. I don't think you can run ARM images on an x64 system and I guess that's problem here.